# Is it efficient to return an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I'm fairly new to PHP; most of my programming experience so far has been in C++. So, naturally, I get concerned about efficiency. In C++ you never ever ever return an object or an array at the end of a function, but if you need the data, you just return a pointer.

So my question is: is it bad for efficiency to be using arrays as return values, or does PHP just use a pointer in the background and just not show me for convenience?

Comment: You can pass by reference in PHP too.

Comment: yes its efficient, PHP uses references in the background, good question by the way! +1

Comment: As for development, it's more efficient to look at profiler graphs (and preferrably database queries then) instead of worrying about performance minutae over readability beforehand.

Comment: Ok thanks! Glad I know now.

Comment: @user2864740 - meda made the claim; mario as far as I can tell didn't make any claim that you're disputing.

Comment: @user2864740 Actually PHP does copy-on-write and the result is that references can even be slower than straight copies. See for example http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php and http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for the link. I didn't realize it utilized CoW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP returns [a reference if it's optimal for the interpreter to do so](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php). Normally parameters passed to functions are copied, though you pass a parameter by reference and therefore get a return value by reference like so:

```
function blah(&$foo) {
  $foo = array();//or whatever
  //note no return statement
}

//elsewhere
$x = "whatever";
blah($x);
//$x is now an array.
```

Because of `&`, `$foo` is treated as a reference, and so modifications to that variable are treated as modifications to the reference.

Or you can force the function to return a reference:

```
function &blah() {
  //some stuff
  return $foo;//goes back as a reference
}
```

This latter shouldn't, according to the docs, be done unless you have a non-optimization reason to do so.

That said, PHP isn't terribly efficient, and worrying about these things is generally premature - unless you're seeing an actual performance bottleneck in your code.